# Me corta el contenido de mi Select en PHP

Tags: php, html

Agradeceré sus aportes para resolver esta gran pequeñez que me atormenta en mi código PHP. En el siguiente código un tema de comillas (aparente) me corta el contenido de mi selección si es que hay 2 palabras. Ej: si es CARDIOLOGIA lo toma completo pero si es CIRUJIA ABDOMEN toma solo Cirujia.
Gracias de antemano.

```php
$combobit="";
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))   
    {
        if($row['tipoespecialidad'] == $especialidad) {
            $combobit .="<option selected value=".$row['tipoespecialidad'].">".$row['tipoespecialidad']."  </option>";
            } else {
            $combobit .=" <option  value=".$row['tipoespecialidad']."> $row['tipoespecialidad']." </option>";
            }
    }

echo "<td><p><select  name='esp' id='esp'> option value='.$combobit.' </select></td></br>";
```

Comment: Veo que en el else te falta una comilla doble justo antes del segundo ``$row``. Si pudieras mostrar el contenido de $row podría ser de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias lo solucione con ese detalle y otros mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no tiene sentido en varios aspectos. Vamos a verlos uno por uno:

1. Declaras una variable (`$combobit`) al principio para ir concatenando. ¡Bien por ti! ese estilo de programación es excelente.
2. Dentro del bucle, todo parece correcto: o un `option` o el otro, según la condición que se cumpla. Aunque eso se puede simplificar, como veremos en el código propuesto.
3. Cuando termina el excelente trabajo dentro de tu bucle  `while`, es ahí donde metes la pata. ¿Qué sentido tiene esto al final del bucle: `option value='.$combobit.'` cuando se supone que los `option` se construyeron completos dentro del bucle?

Te propongo esta solución, aportando además un código más claro y con menos concatenaciones que conducen a la confusión muchas veces:

```
$combobit="";
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))   
    {
        #1. Determinamos la condición con un ternario
        $selected=($row['tipoespecialidad'] == $especialidad) ? "selected" : "";
        #2. Englobamos todo en comillas dobles
        $combobit .="<option $selected value=\"$row[tipoespecialidad]\">$row[tipoespecialidad]</option>";
    }
#3. Aplicamos comillas dobles y corregimos etiquetas
echo "<td><select name=\"esp\" id=\"esp\">$combobit</select></td>";
```

Explico brevemente lo que he hecho:

- #1 Hemos usado un ternario para determinar si el `option` deben llevar o no el estatus `selected`. Ahorramos varias líneas y damos claridad al código
- #2 Hemos englobado todo en comillas dobles. Eso evita tantas concatenaciones y obtenemos tres ventajas: - podemos meter variables dentro, - podemos obtener las claves de arrays sin usar comillas simples, - podemos escribir los nombres de atributos en html estándar (con comillas dobles), a condición de escapar esas comillas con `\` ... aparte de eso, el código es más claro así y los errores más fáciles de detectar.
- #3 Hemos aplicado lo antes dicho sobre comillas dobles. Quitamos una etiqueta `<p>`, además sin etiqueta de cierre, que no hace nada ahí, así como un `</br>`, por lo demás errónea (`</br>` no existe en HTML), que no tendría sentido dentro de una etiqueta `<td>`

Comment: Estimado A.Cedano, gracias por tu aporte. --- Axepto todas tus sugerencias porque ese codigo que puse lo copie de por alli tambien y funciono a medias como les comente. --- Ahora he usado tu codigo que lo veo mas limpio y logico pero me sigue cortando el contenido.---- Favor algo mas podria ser el causante. Gracias.

Comment: @hcc eso puede deberse a varios factores (error en el HTML, reglas css, código Javascript, etc). Explora el código fuente que se está poduciendo y revísalo, si no ves el error agrégalo en la pregunta. Veo que estás metiendo el `select` en el `<td>`  de una tabla, espero que dicha tabla se construya correctamente...

Comment: amigo hace un rato corregi mi post anterior.---- Ya me funciono, con la emocion de tu codigo no cambie el link y me jalaba el anterior script--- mil gracias -- y que Dios te bendiga !!!

Comment: @hcc considera marcar la respuesta que te ha servido para solucionar el problema, así la pregunta no aparecerá como sin resolver y podrá ser de utilidad a otros usuarios con un problema similar. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Bendiciones.